# Google analytics not tracking specific page views

Tags: django, google-analytics

**Issue:** When checking google analytics specific pages on my site are not being tracked. It just shows my websites name for every page view.

[image]

Code:
base .html

```
<head>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-11111"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'G-11111');
</script>
```

other pages:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
```

From what I can tell its configured correctly as it seems to be tracking events properly
[image]
Cant seem to track down the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that report, in your template html you will need to specify a different title for each page. In HTML this looks like...

```
<head>
...
<title>This is my Page Title</title>
...
</head>
```

Because you want it to be different in each template, you can use the following in your base template

```
<head>
<title>{% block htmltitle %}Default title{% endblock %}</title>
```

And then include a different content block in each template

```
{% block htmltitle %}Template type title{% endblock %}
....
```

Comment: For others looking google tracks it by page title